# Matrix dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\{V_i\}_i$ be a set of matrices of complex or real numbers of the same size. Consider the following two statements.

1. $\{V_i^\dagger V_j\}_{i,j}$ is independent.
2. $\{V_i\}_i$ is independent.

Which of the following propositions are true?

$1.\implies 2.$;

$2.\implies 1.$

How would one prove that?

Comment: What $V_i^\dagger$ represent?

Comment: @user264745: the conjugate transpose of matrix $V_i$.

Comment: @user264745: Well, if the size of the matrix is finite, the cardinality of the set should be finite. Otherwise, the cardinality could be infinite. Take your picking. But I am mostly interested in finite size matrices.

Comment: Maybe I was vague. $\{V_i\in M_{m\times n}(F)|\ i\in I\}$, where $F=\Bbb{C}$ and $I$ is index set. I’m asking index set $I$ is finite, countably infinite or uncountably infinite?

Comment: @user264745: The cardinality of $I$ was exactly what I was referring to. If the size of each matrix is finite, or both $m$ and $n$ are finite, the cardinality of $I$ has to be finite for either condition 1 or condition 2 to hold. To make the matter simple, we can simply stipulate $I$ be finite.

Comment: @user264745 He means in order for either independence statement to be true, the set must be finite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $S_1 = \{V_i: i \in I\}$, $S_2 = \{V_{i}^\dagger V_j: i \in I\}$.

It is clear that $1 \implies 2$ by contrapositive. The statement trivially holds if $I = \{\}$, so suppose $I$ is non-empty. Suppose that $S_1$ fails to be independent. Then there exists some $c_j$ (not all zero) such that $\sum_j c_j V_j = 0$. Selecting any $i \in I$, we then have $\sum_{j} c_jV_i^\dagger V_j = V_i^\dagger \sum_j c_j V_j = 0$. Thus, $S_2$ is not independent.

The reverse implication does not hold. As a simple counterexample, consider $S_1 = \{V_1,V_2\}$ with
$$
V_1 = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \quad V_2 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.
$$
$S_1$ is an independent set, but $S_2$ fails to be independent because $V_1^\dagger V_2 = 0$.

More generally, if $S_1$ is any independent subset of $\Bbb C^{m \times n}$ with at least $n+1$  elements, then $S_2$ is a subset of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ of size $(n+1)^2$ and thus cannot be independent.

Comment: Oh, darn. I was thinking along the similar line but failed to set $a_{i,j}:=c_j$ where $a_{i,j}$ is such that $\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}V_i^\dagger V_j=0$. :-(